# Delay loading gif image

Tags: jquery, css, gif

I am displaying a gif loading image before my webpage gets fully loaded. It works fine but when i refresh my webpage, it loads real quick but the gif image get displayed momentarily.

Is there a way to make the gif image appear only 2 seconds after a request for the page is made?

Comment: 2 seconds even if the page is not loaded ? Depending on your answer is document.ready or document.load hiding the loader with $('.loader').delay(2000).fadeOut()

Comment: @drip sorry i guess i wasn't clear. i meant the when you request the page, the gif should appear 2 seconds after the request is made and not immediately. There should be a delay in showing the gif and not hiding it.

Comment: sorry didn't read it well. Then use fadeIn(), not fadeOut() and since you don't want to wait the page to load fully do it on document.ready instead of load.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a timeout to fire after 2 seconds

```
var myLoadingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#thegifimage').show(); // show the image
},2000);
```

and cancel this one when the page is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    clearTimeout(myLoadingTimer); // clearing the timer
    $('#thegifimage').show(); // hiding image tho
});
```

nevertheless it could always happen, that the image is displayed, when the page is loaded after 2010 ms ;)